# How to make VIM Use the Whole Screen While Reading Help?

Tags: neovim, help-system

Why is it, when I search for help, that so much of my screen's vertical space is wasted by default in vim? How can I make it use the whole screen instead. See below:
[image]

Comment: `:help help | only`

Comment: @kadekai : Thank you. That works, but it sure appears rather redundant. I consider each keystroke a step and that's 12 more steps!

Comment: command! -nargs=1 H help <args> | only

Comment: @kadekai Sorry, I don't understand `command!`. Do you mean `ctrl+!`? I think `command` on a MAC means `ctrl` on a PC, right? I'm not using a MAC.

Comment: `:help command`

Comment: `:command! -nargs=1 H help <args> | only` and then `:H help`. Sorry, I forgot proper formatting before. I assumed you knew about vim commands.

Comment: Also you can do `ctrl + w` then hit `o`